# Preventing google maps infowindow from bubbling

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have a google maps app, that displays in a dropdown menu. The dropdown listens for click events to close the dropdown.

Unfortunately, the google maps [infoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) fires a click event as well, that bubbles up to  my dropdown menu and closes it, when the infoWindow closes.

At the moment, I'm helping myself by analysing the innerHTML property of event.target with a regular expression.

1. Is there a way to prevent the bubbling of the infoWindow event without touching the google maps code?
2. Can you recommend a future-proof way check the event.target if 1. is not possible?

Thanks!